# c++ regexp for not preceded by backslash and preceded by backslash

Tags: c++, regex

I can only find negative lookbehind for this , something like `(?<!\\)`.
But this won't compile in c++ and flex. It seems like both regex.h nor flex support this?

I am trying to implement a shell which has to get treat special char like `>`, `<` of `|` as normal argument string if preceded by backslash. In other word, only treat special char as special if not preceded by 0 or even number of '\'

So `echo \\>a` or `echo abc>a` should direct output to `a`
but `echo \>a` should print `>a`

What regular expression should I use?
I'm using flex and yacc to parse the input.

Comment: Which library are you referring to? C++98 did not have a normative regex library. In C++11 you have std::regex: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex. Also you probably need to escape the backslash twice if it is stored in a string: `"…(?<!\\\\)…"`

Comment: Are you trying to do escaping? Is there a specific reason you want to use regex?

Comment: Backslashes in C strings require their own escapes, show the code you're using to build the regex

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that I'm doing the pattern matching in flex. I tried (?<!\\)> for ">" which does not work so I decided to try <regex.h> in C++ to find out which pattern I should use.

Answer (score 1):

In a Flex rule file, you'd use `\\` to match a single backslash '\' character. This is because the `\` is used as an escape character in Flex.

```
    BACKSLASH           \\
    LITERAL_BACKSLASH   \\\\
    LITERAL_LESSTHAN    \\\\<
    LITERAL_GREATERTHAN \\\\>
    LITERAL_VERTICALBAR \\\\|
```

If I follow you correctly, in your case you want "\>" to be treated as literal '>' but "\\>" to be treated as literal '\' followed by special redirect. You don't need negative look behind or anything particularly special to accomplish this as you can build one rule that would accept both your regular argument characters and also the literal versions of your special characters.

For purposes of discussion, let's assume that your argument/parameter can contain any character but ' ', '\t', and the special forms of '>', '<', '|'. The rule for the argument would then be something like:

```
    ARGUMENT ([^ \t\\><|]|\\\\|\\>|\\<|\\\|)+
```

Where:

`[^ \t\\><|]` matches any single character but ' ', '\t', and your special characters
`\\\\` matches any instance of "\" (i.e. a literal backslash)
`\\>` matches any instance of ">" (i.e. a literal greater than)
`\\<` matches any instance of "\<" (i.e. a literal less than)
`\\\|` matches any instance of "\|" (i.e. a literal vertical bar/pipe)

Actually... You can probably just shorten that rule to:

```
    ARGUMENT ([^ \t\\><|]|\\[^ \t\r\n])+
```

Where:

`[^ \t\\><|]` matches any single character but ' ', '\t', and your special characters
`\\[^ \t\r\n]` matches any character preceded by a '\' in your input except for whitespace (which will handle all of your special characters and allow for literal forms of all other characters)

If you want to allow for literal whitespace in your arguments/parameters then you could shorten the rule even further but be careful with using `\\.` for the second half of the rule alternation as it may or may not match " \n" (i.e. eat your trailing command terminator character!).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot easily extract single escaped characters from a command-line, since you will not know the context of the character. In the simplest case, consider the following:

```
 LessThan:\<
 BackslashFrom:\\<
```

In the first one, `<` is an escaped character; in the second one, it is not. If your language includes quotes (as most shells do), things become even more complicated. It's a lot better to parse the string left to right, one entity at a time. (I'd use `flex` myself, because I've stopped wasting my time writing and testing lexers, but you might have some pedagogical reason to do so.)

If you really need to find a special character which shouldn't be special, just search for it (in C++98, where you don't have raw literals, you'll have to escape all of the backslashes):

```
 regex: (\\\\)*\\[<>|]
     (An even number -- possibly 0 -- of \, then a \ and a <, > or |) 
 as a C string => "(\\\\\\\\)*\\\\[<>|]"
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention i am doing the matching inside flex.  any suggestion? Also, I am trying to get special character without '\' (even number of '\' to be precise) in front of them.